# How to start an application in a given directory, using other as its working dir?

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

For a system we are deploying for our customer we need to run the setup executable from %temp% and have it use for the installation, files in another directory.
This cannot be solved at the application level.
So, basically what I need it to somehow "cheat" the setup.exe located at %temp% to think it ran under another directory.

Any ideas?
I tried doing pushd & popd, that doesn't work because the OS tries to call setup.exe from the data files' directory, not setup.exe.
I also tried calling setup.exe by running a bat from the data files directory, that basically calls it by doing:

```
%temp%\setup.exe
```

doing:

```
cd %temp%
setup.exe
```

also failed

Answer (score 0):

cd %files_dir%
%temp%\setup.exe

But
1) it's up to setup.exe to use current dir or not. So this command sequence can have no effect.
2) current dir can be changed at any moment (e.g. when system Files Open dialog is called).

Comment: Hi, yes, that's what I tried and it didn't work.
Is there anyway to create at the OS level a composite directory, that includes files from both directories, without having to copy them?
Junction points wouldn't work, I think.

Comment: Hard links? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create shrtcut of files in %temp% dir and use them instead of files. Maybe you'll need to play around with file extensions.